# Handling multiple IDs in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Can multiple ids be handled like in the code?

```
<script>
$("#segement1, #segement2, #segement3").hide()
</script>

<div id="segement1"/>
<div id="segement2"/>
<div id="segement3"/>
```

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Yes, [`#id` selectors](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) combined with a [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) (comma) is perfectly valid in both jQuery and CSS.

However, for your example, since `<script>` comes *before* the elements, you need a `document.ready` handler, so it waits until the elements are in the DOM to go looking for them, like this:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $("#segement1,#segement2,#segement3").hide()
  });
</script>

<div id="segement1"></div>
<div id="segement2"></div>
<div id="segement3"></div>
```

Comment: If there are no contents for div we can just write <div id="segment1" />  right?

Comment: @Rajeev - nope, it's not a self-closing element :)

Comment: What if these divs are generated automatically #segment{i} and there are an undefine quantity of them ?

Comment: @Reveclaire If you had to, use a ["starts with" attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) like this: `$("[id^=segement]").hide()` (scoping it a bit to whatever the parent is wouldn't be a bad idea).

Answer (score 1):

## Solution:

To your secondary question

```
var elem1 = $('#elem1'),
    elem2 = $('#elem2'),
    elem3 = $('#elem3');
```

You can use the variable as the replacement of selector.

> elem1.css({'display':'none'}); //will work

In the below case selector is already stored in a variable.

> $(elem1,elem2,elem3).css({'display':'none'}); // will not work