# How can I set an attribute on multiple IDs with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
         $('#loginLink, #registerLink')
            .attr('data-disabled') === 'yes'
```

I am trying to set the data-disabled attribute on the IDs but it does not seem to work. Am I using the correct jQuery?

Comment: The question has been answered in another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604099/handling-multiple-ids-in-jquery

Comment: try as given in this post, using each function http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079011/jquery-multiple-id-selectors

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should set the value this way:

```
$('#loginLink, #registerLink').attr('data-disabled', 'yes');
```

As data is a property, you can use `data` method instead:

```
$('#loginLink, #registerLink').data('disabled', 'yes');
```

Comment: On using data, beware that it would not be available as an attribute anymore

Comment: @Adrian Yes, the value is stored as a property. As we use `prop` for `selected` or `checked` properties we should use `data` for `data-*` attributes.

Answer (score 4):

You set the value of an attribute like this:

```
$('#loginLink, #registerLink').attr('data-disabled','yes');
```

To retrieve a value stored like this, you can either:

```
$('yourselector').attr('data-disabled');
```

or

```
$('yourselector').data('disabled');
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally in jQuery, any attribute should be set as below:

```
$(<selector>).attr("<attr name>", "<attr value>");
```

Hope this Helps!!

Answer (score 0):

`$('#loginLink, #registerLink').attr('data-disabled','yes')`

maybe?  I am not familiar with that attribute, but this is how they are usually attributed.