# Combine 2 Different Selectors With 2 Different Events

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have two selectors that I wish to combine in one piece of code to handle two different selectors.

My current code is as follows:

```
var button_b=$("#button_b");
$('#button_a', button_b).on("click, dblclick", function(){
//do stuff
});
```

This however doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Try: `$("#button_a,#button_b").on()`

Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604099/handling-multiple-ids-in-jquery

Answer (score 1):

I'm still looking for a method to mention 2 separate selectors and bind them with separate events in a single line of code

Consider the following situation

```
$('input:text#voucher_id, button.nav').bind('click keydown', function(e){ // find nav functions to keydown events on #voucher_id and nav buttons
    reload(e,'<?php echo $aVeryLongUrlDynamicallyGenerated; ?>', $('#voucher_id').val(),$('#doctype').val());
});
```

As clear from the code, I would like to bind the same function to click on button and `keydown` on the textField `#voucher_id`, however by using the above mentioned approach, what's happeing is quiet obvious and I am getting the same function activated on `keydown` on buttons, which is non desirable behavior.

How to avoid this and still combine the code for two selected.

Answer (score 0):

Combining selectors ([as mentioned by @mike](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13190478/combine-2-different-selectors-with-2-different-events#comment17954943_13190478)) is a simple matter of coma separating the selector values `$("#button_a,#button_b")`. Events can be separated with spaces -

```
var selector = '#bar';
$("#foo,"+selector).on("click dblclick", handler);
```

These two events will be hard to catch on the same element. The first click of a double click will get picked up and call the handler, you won't be able to squeeze in a double click before the handler is called for the single click.

My live demo here uses the same technique but with a `mouseenter` and `click` events.

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VSY2V/)

Comment: Ah you are right. I think I should reword what I aim for it to do. "Button B" uses the dblclick and Button A just the click event, but both events use the same code if that makes sense.

Comment: Well then my example would still work for you. As you can see, I didn't write a callback function in the code above, all I did was reference the function `handler()` which is a custom function. So you can simply point both events to the same handler function.

Comment: Yes but then Button B would also receive a click event instead of just the double click.

Answer (score 0):

If that's the case why don't don't you have a same handler and different events for these elements ..

```
$("#button_a").on("click", function(){
     myFunc(this);
});

$("button_b").on("dblclick", function(){
     myFunc(this);
});

function myFunc(elem){
    // Your code here
}
```